# What else must I do to set up a new custom module?

Tags: 7

I am defining my first custom module and cannot get Drupal to see it.

What I have done:

1. Created a subdirectory with module name at sites/all/modules/custom/mymodulename. The name is just letters, nno spaces underscores or dashes.
2. Added two files mymodulename.info & mymodulename.module.
3. mymodulename.info contains: name = mymodulename and includes a description, package = Other, and core = 7.x.
4. ran update.php
5. flushed caches
6. reloaded admin/modules page
7. module is not listed???

I suspect that I somehow let Drupal know this is my first attempt and it is just messing with me! How can I appease it?

Comment: Can you post the content of your .info file?

Comment: OH DAMN! I went to my mymodulename.inf file to get the info for your request and noticed the missing"o" in "info".  I knew when I wrote this the answer would probably embarrass me. That you for your incredible assistance!  Leave a question and I'll check it off for you!

Comment: np, have seen that mistake before=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for spelling mistakes, because you seem to have everything you need for it to be listed.